# How to make Atom cucumber step jump package to work on windows?

Tags: typescript, cucumber, atom-editor, webdriver-io

I just installed Atom text editor. And I installed the cucumber-step package:https://atom.io/packages/cucumber-step.
But when I click `CTRL+ALT+j` it doesn't jump to step `implementation/definition`.
I am on `Windows 10` and I use `webdriverIO 6 framework` with *Typescript* and *cucumber*.
Does anybody have any idea what else could I do in order to make this work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the package only supports Ruby and JavaScript file in `step_definitions` folder.
Also it requires specific folder structure in order for it to work. `step_definitions` folder needs to be placed inside the `features` folder (like `/features/step_definitions`).
I left the issue on the repo trying to request these improvements.
Until they respond it doesn't work for Typescript nor different project structure.